# How to make one name refer to more than one picturebox?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am making a game in which a player moves around and is followed. But with many things following the user, I wanted to know if there was a way to refer to all of these things with one name. I am making the things follow the user like so:

```
if (user.Top < thing1.Top)
    thing1.Top += 5;
else
    thing1.Top -= 5;

if (user.Left < thing1.Left)
    thing1.Left += 5;
else
    thing1.Left -= 5;

if (user.Top < thing2.Top)
    thing2.Top += 5;
else
    thing2.Top -= 5;

if (user.Left < thing2.Left)
    thing2.Left += 5;
else
    thing2.Left -= 5;
```

That code will repeat for however many "things" I include. Each thing is a separate pictureBox. I was wondering if it would be possible to refer to all my "things" with one name. For example if I had 50 of them `thing.Top += 10` would move them all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what "thing" represents, but you could group them into a collection, and just add new `Thing` instances to it as you create them:

```
var things = new List<Thing> { thing1, thing2, thing3 };
```

Then iterate through the collection:

```
foreach (var thing in things)
{
    thing.Left += (user.Left < thing.Left) ? 5 : -5;
    ...
}
```

If this is `WinForms`, it's going to be painfully slow for a game no matter what, but I suppose you already know that if you've been playing around with it.